# Проблема регестрации репозитория через Unity container,ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp

Проект имеет трехслойную архитектуру(дата,бизнес, само представление) и фабрику для управления юнити контейнером.Дата представляет собой UoW репозиторий через EF6 с подходом CodeFirst(используется из-за ASP.NET Identity).
Само исключение(в студии не отлавливается через отладку):

```
[InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта 
"Calendar_.Initialazer.RootContext" к типу "System.String".]
    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +218
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +35
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +10
   Unity.ObjectBuilder.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +188
   Unity.Container.StrategyChain.BuildUp(IBuilderContext builderContext) +133
   Unity.Policy.BuildPlanPolicyExtensions.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuildPlanPolicy policy, IBuilderContext context) +17
   Unity.UnityContainer.BuildUp(Type typeToBuild, Object existing, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +206

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'Calendar_.DAL.Interfaces.IUnitOfWork', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: Resolving parameter 'connectionString' of constructor Calendar_.DAL.Repositories.EFUnitOfWork(System.String connectionString).
Exception is: InvalidCastException - Не удалось привести тип объекта "Calendar_.Initialazer.RootContext" к типу "System.String".
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
  Resolving Calendar_.DAL.Repositories.EFUnitOfWork,(none) (mapped from Calendar_.DAL.Interfaces.IUnitOfWork, (none))
  Resolving parameter 'connectionString' of constructor Calendar_.DAL.Repositories.EFUnitOfWork(System.String connectionString)
```

]
Конструктор RootContext

```
public RootContext(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            _factory = UnitySetup.CreateServiceProviderFactory();
            _mapper = new MapperService();
        }
```

```
public static IServiceProviderFactory CreateServiceProviderFactory()
        {
            return new ServiceProviderFactory(container.Value);
        }
```

```
 public TService GetService<TService>(params object[] resolveParams)
        {
            return _container.Resolve<TService>(new ServiceProviderParametrResolver(resolveParams));
        }
```

Как я понимаю, проблема либо в регистрации моего репозитория, либо в том как я обращаюсь к нему через сервис. Вот регистрация в контейнере(в попытках решить проблему был добавлен InjectionConstructor,но он ничего не поменял)

```
        _container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, EFUnitOfWork>(new InjectionConstructor("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\\Calendar_.mdf';Integrated Security=True"));
```

Обращаюсь к репозиторию я так : 
`using (var Database = Context.Factory.GetService<IUnitOfWork>(Context.RootContext))`
Как это можно исправить?(гугл сильно не помог)

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось банально, просто был неправильный конструктор в моем UOW репозитории

Comment: UoW не стоит использовать в entity framework так как сам framework использует реализацию UoW. Советую вам использовать паттерны CQRS или DDD